# Get a list of files committed to Git ordered by date added

Tags: git, bash

We've got a load of database update queries in our repository to be run sequentially on deploy. Obviously these need to run in order of creation, because 1 file might be a load of `CREATE TABLE` statements, the next one `INSERTS` into that table.

Because Master branch refers to the current Live DB, I want to apply all deltas that haven't yet been applied to live, ie all ones that are in my current branch but Not in the Master branch.

My bash code currently does this, getting all files that are new in my branch that aren't on the master branch:

```
for f in $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A master /sitepath/deltas/)
do
     mysql --verbose -h $HOST -u$2 $PWORD --database $1 < "$f"
     echo "importing $f"
done
```

But that creates a list sorted into alphabetical order by filename. Which sort of works, but I need it ordered from First file committed to last.

Comment: Don't use `diff`? Use `log` instead?

Comment: If I can get it to only show me the file names that are new on my branch...

Comment: `log` takes `--diff-filter` too.

Comment: Sorry; wasn't clear enough. I want all commits that *aren't* on branch Master but *are* on my current branch

Comment: `git log --diff-filter=A master..`?

Comment: that doesn't get me the list of filenames so I can't get to their content :(

Comment: You might need `--name-only` in there also or a custom format string.